# Convert nodata values to 'nan' in QGIS

Tags: qgis, nodata, ascii

I have a raster layer that I want to use in a software program. The program requires nodata values to be 'nan', rather than a number. Currently the no data value is 1,000,000,000. (I'm not sure why its such a large number).

I need an .asc file that looks like this:

```
ncols        2203
nrows        3464
xllcorner    302500.000000000058
yllcorner    81329.999999999767
cellsize     10.000000000000
 nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan
```

Instead it looks like this:

```
ncols        2203
nrows        3464
xllcorner    302500.000000000058
yllcorner    81329.999999999767
cellsize     10.000000000000
NODATA_value  1000000000
 1000000000.0 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000
```

Comment: Couldn't you open your file in a text editor and use replace to turn 1000000000 to nan ?

Comment: @J.R Not really. The actual file is much larger than the sample I've provided. edit: Woops thought you meant manually. Ill give it a go

Comment: There are dozens of ways to do a global search-and-replace, including editor applications, utilities like`sed`, and a 10-20 line program in any computer language.

Comment: I would contact the software developers and ask them to fix their product. The specification of the ASCII Grid format allows any value for nodata if it is advertised in the headers. To require nan is nonsense.

Answer (score 3):

I made a test and nan as a nodata value is accepted by GDAL and ArcMap. Here is my test file:

```
ncols        5
nrows        5
xllcorner    440720.000000000000
yllcorner    3750120.000000000000
cellsize     60.000000000000
nodata_value nan
    107    nan    132    115    132
    115    132    107    123    148
    115    132    140    132    123
    148    132    123    123    115
    132    156    132    140    132
```

For changing the nodata value from 1000000000 into nan I also suggest using search and replace with a text editor.

Comment: Hi I have tried with notepad++ and the programme just freezes. Any advice on a better text editor to use?

Comment: You are probably on Windows so maybe you should use Powershell. See the third answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14108455/how-to-do-a-sed-like-operation-on-windows and for other alternatives https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127318/is-there-any-sed-like-utility-for-cmd-exe.

Comment: I followed this code in R https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23474552/how-to-read-txt-file-and-replace-word-in-r